# Deleting inward-pointing needles from polygons in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, geometry, qgis-3

I have a lot of inward-pointing needles in my polygon layer (as shown in the screenshots below).

It is a not a multipart layer, so only one geometry and I would like to clean/delete those needles. Is there a tool for it? I tried dissolve, but this didn't change anything.

[image: inner-pointing needles]

[image: inner-pointing needles edit mode]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are several options to try. possibly all these yield a reasonable result, but sometimes one needs to be more creative.

Basic options:

1. buffer the layer by a very tiny amount (for example 0.01 meter), then dissolve
2. use `v.clean` the bleacher ;) of all artifacts. You will have to play with some of its options among the ones under `Cleaning tools`.
   Judging from your screenshots I would start by selecting `rmbridge`, `rmdangle`, or `rmline`

Comment: Yeah, great! Or buffer by 0.01 (or: diameter of the needles) and then again with-0.01 to get the orgininal shape back.

Comment: Thank you! v.clean didn't work out, but buffer with a tiny distance is a great way and solves my problem!